# Is firebase storage pricing charged per month?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I currently calculate the cost using Firebase for blaze plan.

The size of Firestore storage is $0.18/GiB
and the size of storage is $0.026/GB.

Is the pricing for Firebase storage calculated and charged per month?

If I have 1000GB images stored, then in a month I have to pay $26?

I just want to make sure, because it is not stated in the pricing page. https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) of Cloud Storage on the Blaze plan is:

> GB stored: 5GB free, then $0.026/GB

This charge is per month indeed. So if you have 10GB stored in a month, you'll pay (10-5) * $0.026 = $0.13 that month. If you still have the 10GB stored in the next month, you'll again pay $0.13 for it.

> GB downloaded: 1 GB/day free, then $0.12/GB

So if 5GB is downloaded from your project in a day, you'll pay (5-1) * $0.12 = $0.48 for that day.

Comment: Hi Fran. Please inlight me. You said "So if you have 10GB stored in a month, you'll pay (10-5) * $0.026 = $0.13 that month.", that is clear. 

My question is: Is this 10gb stay in your firebase the next month you will be charged by this 10gb again? Is this accumulative?

Comment: Yes. You're renting HDD space here, and as long as you use that space you'll pay for it.

Comment: Did they reduce the free quota from 5Gb to 1Gb for firestore?

Comment: This question and answer are about Cloud Storage (file storage), not about Firestore (a nosql database).